# SlideToggle. разварвчивает блок и тут же сворачивает

Tags: jquery, html5

Есть блок

```
<li>
    <a href="" class="arrow"><p>▼</p></a>
    <a href="">Мукотомы</a>
    <ul class="thirdlvl this">
        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">1.1</a></li>
        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">2.1</a></li>
        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">3.1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

и скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.arrow').click(function () {
       $('.this').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Нажимая на arrow блок this пытается развернутся, разварачивается пол секунды, и тут же сварачивается обратно.
Если написать в консоле

```
$('.this').slideDown('slow');
```

ul разварачивается правильно. 
Никто не сталкивался?

Comment: За "пол секунды" успевает перегрузиться страница.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="" class="arrow"><p>▼</p></a>
```

Как вы думаете что будет если нажать на ссылку?)
Убираем href="" и все работает